# transforming a string into a list in python

Tags: python, string, list

For example, I have a `string = "[1,2,3,4]"` and I want to only have the `[1,2,3,4]`, I tried doing `list(mystring)` but it gives me:

```
['[', '1', ',', '2', ',', '3', ',', '4', ']']
```

I just want to chop off the `""` of the string `"[1,2,3,4]"`.

the output I want can be made with the print, it will output:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

but I don't know how to get that output into a variable, can someone help?

Comment: How did you get that string? If it's coming from JSON, you should probably be using the `json` module to load it into a Python list. Otherwise, use Python's own literal parser via `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: I actually get it from " with open("saved_DNA.txt", "r") as f: mypop = f.readline().rstrip() ". there is propably a way to read my text file as a list but right now it works and with ast.literal_eval it output what I need

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
In [3]: import ast

In [4]: s = "[1,2,3,4]"

In [5]: ast.literal_eval(s)
Out[5]: [1, 2, 3, 4]

In [6]: L = ast.literal_eval(s)

In [7]: L
Out[7]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [1]: import json

In [2]: s = "[1,2,3,4]" 

In [3]: json.loads(s)
Out[3]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use some string functions

```
s = "[1,2,3,4]"
s_list = [int(x) for x in s.strip('[]').split(',')]
```

Comment: You could do that, but as Martijn Pieters says, why have a dog and bark yourself? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension and check for digits, like:

```
 s = "[1,2,3,4]"
 lst = [int(x) for x in s if x.isdigit()]
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: That won't work so well if there are any numbers with more than one digit.